# Do the MSBuild Community Tasks or Extension Pack work with Mono's xbuild?

Tags: msbuild, mono, msbuildcommunitytasks, xbuild, msbuildextensionpack

Has anyone got the [MSBuild Community Tasks](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/) or [MSBuild Extension Pack](http://msbuildextensionpack.codeplex.com/) working with Mono's [xbuild](http://www.mono-project.com/Microsoft.Build)? They both seem to have MSI installer, so I guess it's a case of manually transferring the files to the Mac (in my case)?

If anyone's done it, I'd appreciate the benefit of his/her experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have to do it manually because of the MSI.
You can get the sources :
http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/files/documents/3383/36642/MSBuild.Community.Tasks.v1.2.0.306.zip
http://msbuildextensionpack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets#

And compile them with xbuild. Then you should be able to use them with xbuild.

Nevertheless, I'd never tried.

Comment: After compiling, where did you place the assemblies?